# All circles being drawn in the same colour

Tags: javascript, canvas

Shortly summarized the problem is this. I want to draw two circles on the canvas with different colors. For some reason, they are drawn in the same color, even though the console log I have placed in is switching between "green" and "blue". Sorry that some of the variable names are in my native language if that poses a problem just ask and I'll translate it.

```js
var bodyEl = document.querySelector("body");
var canvasEl = document.createElement("canvas");
var height = window.innerHeight;
var width = window.innerWidth;
canvasEl.height = height;
canvasEl.width = width;
bodyEl.appendChild(canvasEl);
var ctx = canvasEl.getContext("2d");
var obj = [];

class ball {
  constructor(radius, farge, xPosisjon, yPosisjon) {
    this.x = xPosisjon;
    this.y = yPosisjon;
    this.rad = radius;
    this.farge = farge;
  }
  get areal() {
    let areal = "areal: " + (Math.PI * this.rad * this.rad + "px");
    return (areal);
  }
  tegn() {
    //console.log(this.farge);
    ctx.fillStyle = this.farge;
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.rad, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
  }
}

obj.push(new ball(20, "green", 100, 100));
obj.push(new ball(30, "blue", 500, 300));

setInterval(() => {
  obj.forEach(x => {
    x.tegn();
  });
}, 30);
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Did you mean to direct that at me?  The OP doesn't have a clear command, but my answer does.  I was trying to figure out what the root of the problem was and thought it might be because shapes were not getting cleared.  I didn't want to have to get the size of the canvas out so I just did a 500, 500 size as a quick and dirty way to make sure.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a [`ctx.beginPath()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/beginPath).

The reason you are seeing the same color is related to the same problem found in this question: [Drawing lines with canvas by using for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23877988/691711).  If you don't use `beginPath()`, you keep pushing draw commands to the same (root) path and then drawing the ever increasingly complex path.

You have to use `beginPath` to start a sub-path.  `ctx.fill()` will close the sub-path.  The `closePath` [is optional](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes).

> The third, and an optional step, is to call `closePath()`. This method
>   tries to close the shape by drawing a straight line from the current
>   point to the start. If the shape has already been closed or there's
>   only one point in the list, this function does nothing.

```js
var bodyEl = document.querySelector("body");
var canvasEl = document.createElement("canvas");
var height = window.innerHeight;
var width = window.innerWidth;
canvasEl.height = height;
canvasEl.width = width;
bodyEl.appendChild(canvasEl);
var ctx = canvasEl.getContext("2d");
var obj = [];

class ball {
  constructor(radius, farge, xPosisjon, yPosisjon) {
    this.x = xPosisjon;
    this.y = yPosisjon;
    this.rad = radius;
    this.farge = farge;
  }
  get areal() {
    let areal = "areal: " + (Math.PI * this.rad * this.rad + "px");
    return (areal);
  }
  tegn() {
    //console.log(this.farge);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.farge;
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.rad, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
  }
}

obj.push(new ball(20, "green", 100, 100));
obj.push(new ball(30, "blue", 500, 300));

setInterval(() => {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,500);
  obj.forEach(x => {
    x.tegn();
  });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Note that ctx.fill doesn't close the sub-path, it will use an enclosed version of it to perform the filling, but the sub-path is not modified. And contrary to what its name could imply, closePath is not the counter of beginPath, it's just a lineTo last movedTo point

Answer (score 0):

your paths are being drawn in the correct colors, but your second (blue) arc is drawing on top of your first (green) one. at the top of your `tegn` method, add a call to [ctx.beginPath()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/beginPath) to let your canvas know that your paths should be independent.

Answer (score 0):

You missed `beginPath`.

```js
var bodyEl = document.querySelector("body");
var canvasEl = document.createElement("canvas");
var height = window.innerHeight;
var width = window.innerWidth;
canvasEl.height = height;
canvasEl.width = width;
bodyEl.appendChild(canvasEl);
var ctx = canvasEl.getContext("2d");
var obj = [];

class ball {
  constructor(radius, farge, xPosisjon, yPosisjon) {
    this.x = xPosisjon;
    this.y = yPosisjon;
    this.rad = radius;
    this.farge = farge;
  }
  get areal() {
    let areal = "areal: " + (Math.PI * this.rad * this.rad + "px");
    return (areal);
  }
  tegn() {
    //console.log(this.farge);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.farge;
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.rad, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
  }
}

obj.push(new ball(20, "green", 100, 100));
obj.push(new ball(30, "blue", 500, 300));

setInterval(() => {
  obj.forEach(x => {
    x.tegn();
  });
}, 30);
```